# How do you find a maximum value in a Swift dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

So, say I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
var data : [Float:Float] = [0:0,1:1,2:1.414,3:2.732,4:2,5:5.236,6:3.469,7:2.693,8:5.828,9:3.201]
```

How would I programmatically find the highest value in the dictionary? Is there a "data.max" command or something?

Comment: `let maxValue = data.sort{$0.1 < $1.1}.last // (.0 8, .1 5.828)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Your answer works, but `sort()` it's not an efficient way to solve this problem it takes `O(nlogn)` and the default `maxElement ` takes `O(n)`.

Comment: @VictorSigler Your answer seems the correct approach

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
let maximum = data.reduce(0.0) { max($0, $1.1) }
```

Just a quick way using `reduce`.

or:

```
data.values.max()
```

Output:

```
print(maximum) // 5.828
```

Comment: `maxElement()` has been renamed to `max()`.

Answer (score 34):

A Swift Dictionary provides the max(by:) method. The Example from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2296181-max) is as follows:

```
let hues = ["Heliotrope": 296, "Coral": 16, "Aquamarine": 156]
let greatestHue = hues.max { a, b in a.value < b.value }
print(greatestHue)
// Prints "Optional(("Heliotrope", 296))"
```

Comment: Thank u very much !!! really thanks for posting, and also for apple link

Answer (score 6):

Exist a function in the API, named [`maxElement`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceType_SsS_10maxElementuRq_S__Fq_FzFzTqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7Elementqqq_S_9GeneratorS0_7Element_SbGSqqqq_S_9GeneratorS0_7Element_) you can use it very easy , that returns the maximum element in `self` or `nil` if the sequence is empty and that requires a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) as closure in your case as you use a Dictionary. You can use like in the following example:

```
var data : [Float:Float] = [0:0,1:1,2:1.414,3:2.732,4:2,5:5.236,6:3.469,7:2.693,8:5.828,9:3.201]
let element = data.maxElement { $0.1 < $1.1} // (.0 8, .1 5.828)
```

And get the maximum value by the values, but you can change as you like to use it over the keys, it's up to you.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 4):

There are two methods to find max value in the dictionary.

First approach:

```
data.values.max
```

Second approach:

```
data.max { $0.value < $1.value}?.value
```

If you want to find max key:

```
data.max { $0.key < $1.key}?.key
```

Answer (score 3):

Honestly the solutions mentioned above - work, but they seem to be somewhat unclear to me as a newbie, so here is my solution to **finding the max value in a Dictionary** using **SWIFT 5.3** in **Xcode 12.0.1**:

```
var someDictionary = ["One": 41, "Two": 17, "Three": 23]

func maxValue() {

    let maxValueOfSomeDictionary = someDictionary.max { a, b in a.value < b.value }
    print(maxValueOfSomeDictionary!.value)
  
}

maxValue()
```

After the *dot notation* (meaning the ".") put *max* and the code inside *{}* (curly braces) to compare the components of your Dictionary.