# "Missing return" in function that finds the key with min/max value in dictionary

Tags: swift

I have defined the following function to find the minimum key value in a dictionary:

```
func keyMinValue(dictionary: [String: Double])-> String{

    for (key,value) in dict{
        if value == dict.values.minElement(){
            return key
        }
    }
}
```

An error indicates that my code is:

> Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'

I've used this same logic in Python code before and it works. I am new to Swift, so there maybe something I am missing here. Does the function not break at the first instance of return?

Comment: If the key is not found, then the method won't return anything. That's probably your case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you find a maximum value in a Swift dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232922/how-do-you-find-a-maximum-value-in-a-swift-dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

You are close. The problem is if there are no elements in the dictionary, what is returned? You may consider making the return value `Optional`, and returning `nil` if no element is found.

```
func keyMinValue(dict: [String: Double]) -> String? {

    for (key, value) in dict {
        if value == dict.values.minElement() {
            return key
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: So it would be safe to assume that in Swift, you should always consider the "nil" case when calling upon functions, enums, structs, classes, etc...

Comment: Yes, definitely. The nice thing about Swift is that it helps you do that. In a lot of other languages, it's very easy to inadvertently try to use a `nil` value to do something that may cause a crash.

`Optional`s explicitly let you know that it's possible the value may not be there, so you can handle it properly. If something isn't `Optional`, it is pretty much guaranteed at compile time that it will work. See more details, here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/247/optionals/5984/overview-why-optionals